# I removed two three-way electrical switches; they don’t work now

Tags: wiring

[image][image]

The first picture is the switch that is wired to electrical panel.

Comment: What do you mean by "removed"? Just demounted from wall electrical box?

Comment: What was your motivation for "removing" the switches? Painting? Replacement with smart switch technology? Curiosity? ....

Comment: In my experience, electrical switches never work after you remove them. Did you remove and put them back? Did you replace them with new switches? Please describe what you did or else you are going to get useless answers based on wild guesses.

Answer (score 7):

Notice one of the screws is black? The other two are brass.

Get a 5-pack of colored electrical tape and mark both of the **wires to the brass screws** with yellow  tape.  Those are travelers and they go to the same place, in the same cable, and are interchangeable (no need to tell them from each other).

This makes 3-ways a lot easier to deal with.

Also, hook the wires around the screws, they are far more reliable than backstabs. For one thing you can see if they are engaged properly.

Comment: How do I know that those are the travelers for sure

Comment: It's too late to mark the wires now, they're currently wrong.

Comment: @TomQ reread my hints  * they go to the same place * in the same cable

Comment: The red and the black that are together in the same Rome’s sheath are the travelers, connect them to the non-black screw, connect the remaining wire at each end to the black screw.

Comment: Keep in mind there is more than one way to wire a three-way switch.

Answer (score 6):

Harper gave some good advice for marking the wires with colored tape before you go cutting every thing loose.

If the switches worked OK before you demounted them then there is a very high possibility that your problem with the switches is related to:

[image]

This type of connection is notoriously unreliable. If you wanted to check to make sure that the lighting circuit still works you could redo each of the wires on each switch to use the adjacent screws instead. If the lights then start working then you will know that it was one or more of the poke-in wire connections that was at fault.

If the screw terminal switch test reveals that the lights still do not work then the next most likely situation is that one of the switch wires comes from a wire nutted bundle in the electrical box that became intermittent when you flexed the wires whilst demounting the switches.

Comment: I agree Harper gave great advice and will do that and what you suggested and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Invest in a reliable voltage (live wire) tester.  They look like one of those multi-colored pens with a plastic tip.  They will tell you which wire is live in your gang box.  Anyone who is going to play with the wiring in their house needs one of these.

Wire that to your black screw.  The other two are travelers. (one travels to light, the other travels to the other switch)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).